# Internal Server error when communicating to a web api through HTTP Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I am not able to figure out what configuration or code changes has made my code to stop working. It was working fine one month ago. But now when I am trying to call the webapi httpGet method from another api using HttpClient, it is not navigating the debugger to that api. I dont know what is wrong here. Below is the code:

```
if (trackerData.DocumentId.HasValue)
        {
            _logger.Information($"Document id found : {trackerData.DocumentId}");
            Dtos.Read.DocumentDto doc = await _salesEvidenceDocumentService.GetDocumentId(trackerData.DocumentId.Value);
            document.ImageByte = doc?.ImageByte;
            _logger.Information($"ImageByte length: {doc?.ImageByte?.Length}");
        }
```

---

```
public class DocumentService : IDocumentService
{
    private readonly IWebClient _webClient;
    private const string documentEndPoint = "api/LopsMre/getdoc";

    public DocumentService(IWebClient webClient)
    {
        _webClient = webClient;
    }

    public async Task<DocumentDto> GetDocumentId(int documentId)
    {
        return await _webClient.GetAsync<DocumentDto>(documentEndPoint + "?documentID=" + documentId);
    }        
}
```

---

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        var authToken = await _userProvider.GetJwtToken();//successfully getting the bearer token

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            SetHeaderValues(authToken, client); // the base address i.e localhost:4200 is getting added

            var httpResponseMsg = await client.GetAsync(url); //this is not navigating to the webapi method. the method is showing below. getting IsSuccessStatusCode as false and internal server error
            if (httpResponseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = await httpResponseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _logger.Information($"Document download success: {url}");
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
            }
            else
            {
                //log error
                _logger.Error($"Document download failed: {url}");
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
[HttpGet()]
    [Route("api/LopsMre/getdoc/")]
    //This is where the httpclient should navigate
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync(int documentID)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TOPS.ConnectionString"];
        var countryCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CountryCode"];
        using (DocDocumentService obj = new DocDocumentService(connectionString))
        {
            var image = obj.GetDocumentByID(documentID, countryCode);
            await SetImageBytes(image);
            return Ok(new { image.LstDocumentView[0].DocumentID, image.ImageByte });
        }
    }
```

---

**web.config**

```
<location path="api/LopsMre">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

IS something missing here that the webapi is not getting called. I have removed the attribute JWTAuthentication to be sure if it is working otherwise. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you got http 500 error while making request(s) using HttpClient? Have you checked event logs?

Comment: yes I have checked everything. Even I tried making changed in applicationhost.config. but to no avail :(

Comment: If you have source code of this app, you can try to redeploy it to your server and test if new deployment can work well.

Comment: Add Try-Catch and log exception there. If you can debug in local then try that as well.